# Missing required parameter for [Route: cat] [URI: category/{category}] [Missing parameter: category]

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am trying to send a static data to component and routes and not getting output.

This is my code -

Blade.php with using component -

```
<x-separator title="Hindi" titleURL="{{ route('cat',$category[0]) }}" />
```

Controller -

```
$category=['hindi','bengali','english','punjabi','tamil'];
return view('welcome',['category'=>$category]);
```

Routes -

```
Route::get('/category/{category}', [ZLController::class, 'cat'])->where('category', '[a-z-]+')->name('cat');
```

I tested below code in blade file -

```
<x-separator title="Hindi" titleURL="{{ dd(route('cat',$category[0])) }}" />
```

Output was -
**http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/hindi**

And still getting this error **Missing required parameter for [Route: cat] [URI: category/{category}] [Missing parameter: category].**

Comment: Is your component being called in a loop and is one of the loop iterations empty?

Comment: No, there is not any loop for this component. But after this component there is another component which is in the loop. One thing I want to tell that without route it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved by this way -

```
Route::get('/category/{category?}', [ZLController::class, 'cat'])->where('category', '[a-z-]+')->name('cat');
```

Comment: All this is doing is making the route parameter optional. Is the parameter actually optional or are you just masking the problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Peppermintology for right now I am masking the problem. Originally my routes does not have any optional parameter, it should be mandatory parameter. I am masking it cause I did not get any proper solution of my problem from any resources and even not from my own logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the data wrong. Try this

```
<x-separator title="Hindi" titleURL="{{ route('cat', ['category' => $category[0]]) }}" />
```

Comment: Still getting same error.

Comment: Are you sure `$category[0]` (`$category` at all) has any value?

Comment: <x-separator title="Hindi" titleURL="{{ dd(route('cat',$category[0])) }}" />

I use dd function to check it is printing the data.